# Undeclared action button identifier for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why won't the following code work on this button? I have a feeling it's something related to being an IBAction instead of being an IBOutlet. But why? All I'm trying to do is move a button.

implementation:

```
 self.testButton.center = CGPointMake(test.center.x, test.center.y+20);
```

header:

```
- (IBAction)testButton:(id)sender;
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you dont have clear knowledge about `IBAction` and `IBOutlet`. Here you want an outlet of the button not an action since you changing a property of the button. Code will looks like

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *testButton;
```

**Outlet** : is used when we want to interact with an object in Xib/Storyboard programmatically

**Action** : is meant for controls like UIButton,UISegmentedControl.. to inform the controller when its get tapped or some other intended actions

Comment: Your right, I'll have to brush up on that. I guess my question is more related to how do I use a button that's an Outlet that can still be used as an action?

Comment: You should have outlet and action separately

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect the button to your IBAction in InterfaceBuilder or in your Storyboard. Otherwise testButton is never called.

Here's a short tutorial:
http://www.appcoda.com/hello-world-app-using-xcode-5-xib/